# In PHP, is there any way to automatically name a class based on the filename?

Tags: php, class, boilerplate

I tried to do the following (which did not work):

`class basename(__FILE__, '.php')`

Answer (score 2):

No, you must specify the class name.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use `basename()` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get current page file name
that's  what i understood from your question

php file

```
 $filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

then compare the class with variable